# Ruby method calls without defining variables

Tags: ruby, symbols

I am beyond confused on where the :find is coming from line 17, as well as :findcity... is that how you call a fucntion within a predefined method call from ruby???

```
 cities = {'CA' => 'San Francisco',
 'MI' => 'Detroit',
 'FL' => 'Jacksonville'}

 cities['NY'] = 'New York'
 cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

 def find_city(map, state)
   if map.include? state
     return map[state]
   else
     return "Not found."
   end
 end

 # ok pay attention!
 cities[:find] = method(:find_city)

 while true
   print "State? (ENTER to quit) "
   state = gets.chomp

   break if state.empty?

   # this line is the most important ever! study!
   puts cities[:find].call(cities, state)
 end
```

Comment: You're inserting the `Method` object that represents `find_city` with the `:find` key.

Comment: Please don't copy line numbers in code samples. It makes it more difficult to debug samples.

Comment: @August what object represents find_city? do you think that it just wasn't presented in this portion of the code/

Comment: ... `find_city` is the method defined immediately above where you call `method(:find_city)`. The `:find_city` symbol is being used to get capture the method *itself*. You then call it with `cities[:find].call(cities, state)`.

Comment: @scerrecrow It's a [`Method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Method.html) object, obtained using [`Object#method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-method).

Comment: If, as the code comments seem to imply, this is course material, it might be time to find another instructor. Very few Rubyists would consider this to be conventional or useful application of language features.

Comment: @mattt This is from Learn Ruby the Hard Way (earlier edition).

Comment: What is the best resource for a beginner in ruby, but I have a fairly good grasp on java/C already. Anyone have any suggestions on the best way to learn Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

For starters if you are a beginner in Ruby just don't bother trying to understand it. This is not the usual way of doing things in Ruby.

But here are some explanations:

`:find` is a [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Symbol.html) and it could be :search or something else in this example.

You could actually use a different variable to store the method instead of storing inside the cities [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html). Like so:

```
# Instead of doing this
hash = {} # => {}
hash[:puts_method] = method(:puts)
hash[:puts_method].call("Foo")
# Foo

# You can just
puts_method = method(:puts)
puts_method.call("Foo")
# Foo
```

The `find_city` is the method defined in your code. Passing the symbol `:find_city` to the method `method` returns you an object representing that method (very meta uh?) of the class [Method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Method.html).

So like in the example above we can have an object representing the method `puts` with which we can send the method `call` to *call* it.

```
the_puts = method(:puts) 
# => #<Method: Object(Kernel)#puts>
the_puts.call("Hey!")
# Hey!
# => nil

# Which is the same as simply doing
puts("Hey!")
# Hey!
# => nil
```